# Google Earth Super Overlay to TIFF

Tags: google-earth

Is there a way to convert a raster Google Earth Super Overlay to TIFF?
My Google Earth source contains raster tiles.

Comment: Do you have Google Earth Pro?

Comment: No. Is it possibile to do it in pro version?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Earth Pro when you go to File Save Image (Ctrl+Alt+S) you get a dialog box which you can create a 4800x3156 image (only jpg)
but can simply use paint to rewrite a TIFF.

**Please Note** this option for (Low,Medium,High, Premium quality) is only available with Google Earth Pro.

You can try for free
http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/earthpro.html

Cost is Unit Price: 1 - 10 $399.00 - Google Earth Pro is licensed annually per user

[image]